# Is there any way to run 2 node.js servers from elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an angular web app which relies on a node backend and a database, but I don't want to force all of the backend logic as well as the interaction with the database into one file/app. Is there any way to have an instance to deal with the backend and another to make requests to the database? If not, do you have a suggestion for a better way to do this? I couldn't seem to find a better solution elsewhere for deploying to beanstalk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default AWS Elastic Beanstalk uses "npm run start" to start node applications, you could modify it as you like to run both apps depending on your use case

In this example we are going to assume your root folder is holding the client files.. so you would yarn start your client files & cd into server-api folder & start the server

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn start\" \"cd ../server-api && node server.js\""
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But this is all that you have to **setup yourself**.

EB will only "easily" allow you to setup your primary, front-end application, in a sense that it will make sure it restarts when instance it booted or crashes, it runs in correct environment, and more.

For the second application you have to setup it yourself (using **`.ebextentions` or platform hooks**), like you would on a regular linux.

To help **manage starting** your second app you can use [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html) which can reduce an amount of setup needed to ensure that your second app always runs.

Answer (score -3):

Elastic Beanstalk allows you to manage the database instance directly from your application.
When you create it, you can go to "Configure More Options".
Your two tiers will be though in two separate instances.